# Can't remove old chart by d3 svg exit

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have implement a bar chart to show statistic, but when I update the SVG with new data the old bar won't be remove.
Can someone help to clarify the problem.
I use updateStatisticData to update my chart.

```
var cwidth = 800, cheight = 900;
var margin = {top: 80, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 150};
var dataset = {
            "series": ["Fail","Pass"],
            "colors": ["#e74c3c","#2ecc71"]
};
var width = cwidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = cheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;


function getStatisticData() {


$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("/statistic-test-result", { "_": $.now() }, function(msg, status){
        data = msg['result']; //[{"ip":"x.x.x.x", "pass": 3, "fail": 7, 'total':10}, {...}]

        var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .3);
        var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(x)
                      .orient("top");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(yScale)
                      .orient("left");

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.append('text')
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + ",-" + (margin.top / 2) + ")")
           .style("text-anchor", "middle")
           .text("Max test items")

        yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
            return d.ip;
        }));

        x.domain([0, 17]);

        svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "x axis")
           .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "y axis")
           .call(yAxis);

        // add legend
        var legend = svg.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "legend")

        legend.selectAll('text')
              .data(dataset["colors"])
              .enter()
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", width-margin.right - 25 - margin.left)
              .attr("y", function(d, i){ return  -(margin.top / 2) - i * 20})
              .attr("width", 10)
              .attr("height", 10)
              .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d;
              })

        legend.selectAll('text')
              .data(dataset["series"])
              .enter()
              .append("text")
              .attr("x", width-margin.right - margin.left)
              .attr("y", function(d, i){ return -(margin.top / 2) + 9 - i * 20})
              .text(function(d){return d});

        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                      .data(data);

        bars.enter().append('g').attr("class", "bar");

        bars.append("rect")
            .attr({
                'fill':'#e74c3c',
                'width':function(d) {
                    return x(d.fail);
                },
                'height': function(d) {
                    return yScale.rangeBand();
                },
                'y': function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.ip);
                }
            });

        bars.append('text')
            .text(function(d) {
                if (d.fail > 0)
                    return d.fail;
            })
            .attr({
                'fill':'#000',
                'y': function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.ip) + yScale.rangeBand()/2;
                },
                'x': function(d) {
                    return 5;
                }
           });

        bars.append("rect")
            .attr({
                'fill':'#2ecc71',
                'width':function(d) {
                    return x(d.pass);
                },
                'height': function(d) {
                    return yScale.rangeBand();
                },
                'y': function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.ip);
                },
                'x':function(d) { return x(d.fail);
                }
            });

        bars.append('text')
            .text(function(d) {
                if (d.pass > 0)
                    return d.pass;
            })
            .attr({
                'fill':'#000',
                'y': function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.ip) + yScale.rangeBand()/2;
                },
                'x': function(d) {
                    return 5 + x(d.fail);
                }
           });

        return true;
    });
});

}
function updateStatisticData() {

$.get("/statistic-test-result", { "_": $.now() }, function(msg, status){
    data = msg['result']; //[{"ip":"x.x.x.x", "pass": 3, "fail": 7, 'total':10}, {...}]

    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .3);
    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("top");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(yScale)
                  .orient("left");
    yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.ip;
    }));
    x.domain([0, 17]);

    svg.selectAll("g.y.axis")
       .call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll("g.x.axis")
       .call(xAxis);

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                  .data(data);
    bars.exit().remove(); //remove old bars
    bars.enter().append('g').attr("class", "bar");

    bars.append("rect")
        .attr({
            'fill':'#e74c3c',
            'width':function(d) {
                return x(d.fail);
            },
            'height': function(d) {
                return yScale.rangeBand();
            },
            'y': function(d) {
                return yScale(d.ip);
            }
        });

    bars.append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            if (d.fail > 0)
                return d.fail;
        })
        .attr({
            'fill':'#000',
            'y': function(d) {
                return yScale(d.ip) + yScale.rangeBand()/2;
            },
            'x': function(d) {
                return 5;
            }
       });

    bars.append("rect")
        .attr({
            'fill':'#2ecc71',
            'width':function(d) {
                return x(d.pass);
            },
            'height': function(d) {
                return yScale.rangeBand();
            },
            'y': function(d) {
                return yScale(d.ip);
            },
            'x':function(d) { return x(d.fail);
            }
        });

    bars.append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            if (d.pass > 0)
                return d.pass;
        })
        .attr({
            'fill':'#000',
            'y': function(d) {
                return yScale(d.ip) + yScale.rangeBand()/2;
            },
            'x': function(d) {
                return 5 + x(d.fail);
            }
       });


    return true;
});
```

}

Comment: Remove the svg and redraw it again

Comment: This is the simple way, but I want to keep some information on the SVG which doesn't change.
Only the bar chart and y axis need to change.

Comment: Design the code in modular pattern and put drawBar and drawYaxis external. Use this function to draw the chart with new y-scale for new dataset

Comment: I found out how to solve this problem. Use below to replace bars.exit().remove();

svg.selectAll(".bar").selectAll('rect').remove();
        svg.selectAll(".bar").selectAll('text').remove();
        svg.selectAll(".bar").selectAll('g').remove();